# Converting raster to DEM using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, rgb

I have a .jpeg file with three channels, and would like to convert this to a DEM to generate contours lines to export as a vector. I've added a screenshot below of the image in qgis, and a profile going from what should be highs (yellow) to lows (blue):

[image]

I'm aware that the 'elevation' in this case would be between 0-255, however from the profile of values (using the red channel) I see that the lowest part of the image actually has a small peak, which is incorrect.

Is there a way that I can somehow flatten the channels so that I have a single band where the values are more representative of the 'elevation' changes? FYI using the green or blue color bands do now give better results.

Comment: What is the pixel size?

Comment: The image is 512x512px.

Comment: Your jpeg only has a 0-255 range (ie. colors). Do you want a DEM (from XYZ triplets) where the Z would be elevation?

Comment: I mean how large is each pixel? If > 30 m, your might aswell download a proper DEM. Go to https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/ and search for *ASTER Global Digital Elevation Model V003*